# How can I style a select element as a Bootstrap Dropdown component?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have simple select control:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>My control:</p>
<select class="dropdown font-size-sm" aria-labelledby="dropdown-default-light">
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="10">10</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="25">25</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="50">50</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="100">100</option>
</select>

<p>My control with Bootstrap styling:</p>
<select class="form-select font-size-sm" aria-labelledby="dropdown-default-light">
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="10">10</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="25">25</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="50">50</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="100">100</option>
</select>

<p>Bootstrap Dropdown component:</p>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But I need to accept bootstrap styles as for dropdown https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/

Is there way to do that?

Comment: You can't style select options. Also, the Dropdown component is different in that it doesn't have a selected state. It's just a list. You'd have to write a script to update a hidden input.